# JSF Dialog not opening

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Ok folks, i'm have a issue here: My panels and ajax behavior suddenly stopped to work. They were running perfectly, but suddenly stopped to work. I my JSF page i have a dialog panel (**confirmPanel, newPanel**) that must be open on the click event of commandButtons (**btnNew, btnExclude**). Here is the code for the JSF page.

```
    <ui:define name="content">
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="frmPublico">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="ui-main-div">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p:commandButton id="btnNew" value="Novo" onclick="wvNew.show();" type="button"/>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:growl id="gGlobalMsgs" globalOnly="true" redisplay="false"/>
                    <p:dataTable id="dtPublico" value="#{publicoBean.lstDataTablePublico}" 
                             var="publico" paginator="true" rows="#{publicoBean.maximoLinhasTablePublico}" 
                             paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10" >

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            Públicos
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton type="button" id="btnEdit" image="ui-icon-pencil" /> 
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:commandButton type="button" id="btnExclude" image="ui-icon-circle-close" onclick="wvConfirm.show()" /> 
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Nome
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{publico.nmePublico}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Tipo de público
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{publico.tdTipoPublico}"  />
                        </p:column>

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            Públicos
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>

                    <f:facet name="footer">

                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>

                <!-- Caixas de diálogos -->
                <p:dialog id="dialogNovo" header="Novo público" widgetVar="wvNew" modal="true" appendToBody="false" >
                    <p:panelGrid columns="1">

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="pnlNovoPublico">
                            <!-- Cabeçalho do grid -->
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <!-- <p:messages id="info"/> -->
                                Cadastrar público
                            </f:facet>

                            <!-- Linha 1 -->
                            <h:outputLabel for="txtNomePublico" value="*Nome:"/>
                            <p:inputText id="txtNomePublico" value="#{publicoBean.nome}" required="true" requiredMessage="Digite o nome do público." />
                            <p:message for="txtNomePublico" redisplay="false" id="msgNomePublico" />

                            <!-- Linha 2 -->
                            <h:outputLabel for="ddlTipoPublico" value="*Tipo de público:"/>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="ddlTipoPublico" value="#{publicoBean.tipoPublicoSelecionado}" effect="fade" 
                                         converter="#{publicoBean.conversor}" 
                                         required="true" requiredMessage="Selecione um tipo de público."> 
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione um item..." itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{publicoBean.lstMenuTipoPublico}" var="pt" itemLabel="#{pt.label}" itemValue="#{pt}"></f:selectItems>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <p:message for="ddlTipoPublico" redisplay="false" id="msgDdlTipoPublico" />

                        <!-- Rodapé do grid -->
                            <f:facet name="footer">
                                <p:commandButton actionListener="#{publicoBean.cadastrarPublico}" value="Cadastrar" icon="ui-icon-check" ajax="true" update="pnlNovoPublico, msgGlobal"/>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:dialog>

                <!-- Caixa de diálogo de confirmação -->
                <p:confirmDialog id="dialogConfirmExclusao" message="Tem certeza que deseja excluir este item?"
                             header="Confirmar exclusão" severity="alert" widgetVar="wvConfirm">
                    <p:commandButton id="btnConfirm" value="Continuar" oncomplete="wvConfirm.hide()"
                                 actionListener="#{publicoBean.excluirPublico}" />
                    <p:commandButton id="btnCancel" value="Cancelar" onclick="wvConfirm.hide()" type="button" /> 

                </p:confirmDialog>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The **Id** and **WidVar** attributes are different. When i open the Javascript console and hit **wvNew** and **wvConfirm**, they are undefined. What maybe happening?

Comment: did you change anything before they stopped working? did you change primefaces version?

Comment: @Damian No, i didn`t change. But curiosly it is working now. I created another page and went adding component by component (h:form, p:panelGrid, p:dialog). And it is now working. But i didn't figured out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PrimeFaces documentation:

> Use appendToBody with care as the page definition and html dom would
>   be different, for  example if dialog is inside an h:form component and
>   appendToBody is enabled, on the browser  dialog would be outside of
>   form and may cause unexpected results. In this case, nest a form
>   inside a dialog.

Comment: If doing what the documentation says (ie. adding h:form component inside your dialog) solved your problem, you could mark this post as answer. If your code, due to some magic, just started working, compare it with the source contained in your question.

Comment: Ok, following the recommendation solved my problem but now i have another problem. I'll post below.

Answer (score 0):

I altered my xhtml so that it now follows the recommendation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE composition PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="./../../resources/templates/baseTemplate.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">
    <f:view>
        <h:form id="frmPublic">
            <!-- Show general msgs -->
            <p:growl id="gMessages" globalOnly="true" sticky="false" />

            <!-- Show public list -->
            <p:dataTable id="dtPublics" value="#{publicBean.publics}"
                         paginator="true" rows="5" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10"
                         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                         var="actual">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:commandButton id="cbViewNew" value="New" type="button" styleClass="cbViewNew" onclick="dlgNewPublic.show();" />
                </f:facet>
                <!-- Edit and delete columns -->
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton id="cbViewEdit"  image="ui-icon-pencil" 
                                     oncomplete="dlgEditPublic.show()"  title="Edit">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{actual}" target="#{publicBean.selectedPublic}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <p:commandButton id="cbViewDelete" type="button" image="ui-icon-circle-close" onclick="dlgConfirm.show()" title="Delete" /> 
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Name
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel id="olViewPublicName" value="#{actual.publicName}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Public type
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputLabel id="olViewPublicType" value="#{actual.publicType}"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <!-- Caixa de diálogo de inclusão -->
        <p:dialog id="newPublicDialog" widgetVar="dlgNewPublic" modal="true" header="New"
                  resizable="false">
            <h:form id="frmNew">
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <p:outputLabel id="olNewPublicName" value="Name:" for="itNewPublicName"/>
                    <p:inputText id="itNewPublicName" value="#{publicBean.name}" required="true"
                                 requiredMessage="Enter the name"/>
                    <p:outputLabel id="olNewPublicType" for="somNewPublicType" value="Public type:"/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="somNewPublicType" value="#{publicBean.selectedPublicType}" effect="fade" 
                                     converter="#{publicBean.converter}" 
                                     required="true" requiredMessage="Select a public type"> 
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="-- Select --" itemValue=""/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{publicoBean.lstPublicType}" var="actual" itemLabel="#{actual.label}" itemValue="#{actual}"></f:selectItems>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:commandButton id="cbNewSave" value="Save" update=":dlgNewPublic" actionListener="#{publicBean.save}" icon="ui-icon-check" 
                                      oncomplete="dlgNewPublic.hide();" />
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancel" immediate="true" onclick="dlgNewPublic.hide()"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:message id="mNewPublicName" for="itNewPublicName" redisplay="false" />
                        <p:message id="mNewPublicType" for="somNewPublicType" redisplay="false"  /> 
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </f:view>
</ui:define>
```

My bean save method is as follows:

```
...

private String name;
private PublicType publicType;
private PublicDao publicDao;
private List<Public> publics;
// Getters and Setters

...

// Actions e listeners
public void save(ActionEvent ex) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage();
    try {
        TbPublic p = new TbPublic();
        p.setName(getName() );
        p.setTdTipoPublico(getPublicType());

        publicDao.save(p);

        // Showing success msg
        msg.setSummary("Success!");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        context.addMessage(null, msg);

        // Load the list of public again
        publicList = publicDao.getAll();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        msg.setSummary("Error !");
        msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        context.addMessage(null, msg);
    }
}
```

When i click the New button, my dialog opens up perfectly. But after i fill the necessary info and click the Save button, nothing happens. Why this is happening?

Comment: You don't need the extra `ActionEvent ex` in your function header.
`public void save()` will do the right thing.